# Compilation global variables with warning

Tags: compilation, undefined, warnings, maxima, declare

After compiling the file with the command:

```
compile_file("filename.mac");
```

I am getting a **warning** in the filename.UNLISP:

> warning: encountered undefined variable foo in translation.

The documentation says to use the function:

```
define_variable (name, default_value, *mode*);
```

However, if in *mode* I write something other than "any", for example:

```
define_variable(foo, false, boolean)$
```

Then I get the error during recompilation:

> #<function assign-mode-> cannot be printed readably.

Is it possible to declare a variable so that the compilation will be successful without this warning? With mode_declare, declare?

Sample code **filename.mac**:

```
define_variable(foo, true, boolean)$ /* useless string */
foo: true$

exprp(that) := if foo = false and listp(that) and not emptyp(that) and member(that[1], ["+", "*"]) then(foo: true, true)$
matchdeclare(exprm, exprp)$
defrule(rule_1, exprm, subst(exprm[1], "[", exprm[2]))$

calc(list) := block([steps: []],
while foo do(
    steps: endcons(list, steps),
    foo: false,
    list: applyb1(list, rule_1)
),
steps
)$

calc(["+", [["*", [1, 2, 3]], ["+", [3, 4, 6]]]]);
```

Comment: Not sure where the error is coming from exactly, but anyway it's not at all necessary to compile Maxima code; you can just use the interpreted version. Maybe you can say more about what you're doing.

Comment: Can you please post the content of `filename.mac`? It would help us fix the bug. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Added a filename.mac. The real code is more loaded and relates to web-server computing. The error itself is not critical, but it does not allow compiling some really slow files from share \maxima\5.4*.*\src. Thank you for developing Maxima

Comment: Thanks for posting the file. I can see the problem is that Maxima is trying to print a function into the Lisp translation. I won't be able to fix it for a day or two. In the meantime, my advice is to omit the call to `define_variable` and then try compiling the function.

Comment: I've fixed the bug you encountered in commit 3404e9d in Maxima Git. If you want help about how to get the bug fix, you can let me know. This is straightforward if you are accustomed to Git and make; you can tell me where you stand with that.